# How to align elements in ionic 2 using ion-row and ion-col?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I'm trying to achieve a list similar to the one shown here:
http://arunsfolio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/list-petro.png

I'm not sure if I am missing something in sass.

This is the code:

```
 <ion-row>

    <ion-col width-40>
        <h4>Esso</h4>
        <p>Ungrester - 54</p>
        <p>84859 - munch</p>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-40>
        <div class="priceStyle">
            <div class="priceChild">
                $123
            </div>

        </div>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col width-10>
       <div>
        12KM
      </div>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>


SCSS:
.priceStyle {
        background-color: lightblue;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        width: 100px; 
        height: 50px; 
        border-radius: 2px;


    }

.priceChild {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        color: white;
        margin: 0;
        flex: 1;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
```

My code isn't aligning the elements in the centre.

This is how it is displayed right now:

[image]
Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try text-center class in the col or div? Check a few utilities in here http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/css-utilities/

Comment: thanks that helped.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the properties:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

on the 
`<ion-row>` element.

Comment: You should explain why this solves the problem, rather than just posting the solution, to help anyone else who comes across this problem in the future.

Comment: @Jorge Hermosa. On galaxy note3, your solution does not work. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: @smchae nope, I have no idea :(

Comment: just because of `flex`

Comment: everything thanks to flexbox, here a guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/